# Cannot tap UIButton after having set alpha to 0.0, even when reset to 1.0

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have this simple code:

```
func tappedButton() {
   self.button.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 4.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.button.alpha = 0.0
    }) { _ in }
}
```

This function aims at showing a button again for 4 seconds before hiding it (with a 1 second animation). However, while the button is completely visible for these 4 seconds, tapping it doesn't work anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try changing the options to `[.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction]`

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work

Comment: What should happen when you tap it?

Comment: I have an `IBAction` linked to the button, when the view first comes up I can tap the button, the `IBAction` func is called as expected, but after calling this function even if I see the button (with an `alpha` of 1.0), I can't tap it anymore.

Comment: Apple's engineers decided that invisible controls should not be clickable. After set alpha to 1.0. Try to call `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: Did you ever check my answer cause I am  sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in for the method hittest(_:with:) of UIView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

> This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01. This method does not take the view’s content into account when determining a hit. Thus, a view can still be returned even if the specified point is in a transparent portion of that view’s content.

This means that any view, particularly a button, with alpha 0.0 would not be touched.

However, the problem here is that the button is still visible, at least for you. This *odd* behavior occurs because the actual alpha value of the button is *already* setted to 0.0 when the animations starts. Animations work by changing the visual hierachy and transition the difference with the parameters you give to the function. In your case, you have two states: a view with a visible button visible and another view without the button. Only the visual part is animated but the corresponding values are already setted. A solution would be:

```
func tappedButton() {
   self.button.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 4.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.button.alpha = 0.01
    }) { [weak self] _ in self?.button.alpha = 0.0 }
}
```

EDIT: This solution seems like a hack but works. I use this approach because the completion handler is always called with a `true` value.

```
func tapped() {
    let duration = 1.0
    let delay = 2.0
    let delayDuration = delay + duration
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.saveButton.alpha = 0.1
    })
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayDuration, execute: { [weak self] in
        self?.saveButton.alpha = 0.0
    })
}
```

Comment: But it works if I set instead the `alpha` value at something like 0.011 in the `animations:` block, and 0.01 in the completion block. When calling `tappedButton()` and resetting the `alpha` to 1.0, the button is tappable again...

Comment: I updated the answer. The completion handler is always called with a true value if given the `allowUserInteraction` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use allUserInteraction in the options and also check for touches.  The animation is added immediately and although you see the button to the system it is already hidden.  What does this mean?  It means you are watching a movie.  But at least with userInteraction enabled you can check for touch events.  This is great but how do we know the button is really showing or not?  Well you have to use two different checks most likely.  One that checks the true UIView alpha of the button and one check that checks the opacity on the presentation layer.  I have never fully looked at the link between UIView animations and Core Animation except that I think UIView animations are a wrapper for Core Animations.  UIView animations definitely update the view model immediately.  So an alpha animation is most likely interpreted into an opacity animation on the layer.  Armed with this we can check the opacity of the presentation layer on touches and see that the button is being clicked even if the view model thinks the alpha is 0. This check on the presentation layer will work as long as the opacity is above 0.  So here you go.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var testButton : UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: self.view.bounds.width - 40, height: 50))
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        return v
    }()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(testButton)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 4.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.testButton.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

        //test the layer
         //test the layer for opacity
        if let presentation = testButton.layer.presentation()?.animation(forKey: "opacity"){
            print("the animation is already added so normal clicks won't work")
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(){
        print("clicked")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let touch = touches.first{
            let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
            if self.testButton.frame.contains(location){
                //but what you might not know is the animation is probably already running
                //and so the check above misses this
                if let buttonPres = testButton.layer.presentation(),
                    let _ = buttonPres.animation(forKey: "opacity"),
                    let opacity = buttonPres.value(forKey: "opacity") as? CGFloat{
                    if opacity > 0{
                        buttonClicked()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```